# How to create duplicate records with incremental week numbers

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create n duplicates(say 5) of a each record from a table with an increment on the week number associated with each record.

Say there is a table with the following as columns - week, id
and there is a record - 1, John

I want the record for John to repeat 5 times to obtain -

```
1, John

2, John

3, John

4, John

5, John
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can generate a table with five columns and then use that:

```
select (t.week + x.inc) as week, t.name
from t cross join
     (select 0 as inc union all
      select 1 as inc union all
      select 2 as inc union all
      select 3 as inc union all
      select 4 as inc
     ) x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this would cause problems with weeks 52 onward . I want to reset the week numbers to week 1 at the beginning of each year

Comment: @DarshanA . . . That is not the question you asked here.  If you have another question, then provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of what you need, and an appropriate database tag.  Editing this question could lead to downvotes on the answers that already exist -- so that is rather rude.